# Corrupt database on phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, macos, phpmyadmin, xampp

I am very new to phpMyAdmin and XAMPP.

I'm having an issue on the whole phpMyAdmin page. If I create a database, it gives me this error:

## 1932 - Table 'phpmyadmin.pma__tracking' doesn't exist in engine

Running a simple script: SHOW TABLES; - Gives me this:

## 1046 - No database selected

Pretty much nothing works and can't access nothing on the database.

[image]

What can be the issue and how can I fix this? I can't do anything on phpMyAdmin. I even uninstalled it and installed XAMPP back on. Thank you!

Comment: I guess you should ask on http://serverfault.com/ or so, this is not about programming..

Comment: What phpMyAdmin version is this? Does that error appear when you first log in, on every action, or only for some actions? Does your `config.inc.php` include the section for pmadb and the tracking table?

Comment: Have the same issue in MAC latest